# sweeping out colMeans and rowMeans

Tags: r

To sweep out colMeans, rowMeans and mean from columns, rows and observations respectively I use the following code:

```
a <- matrix(data=seq(from=2, to=60, by=2), nrow=6, ncol=5, byrow=FALSE)
b <- matrix(data=rep(colMeans(a), nrow(a)), nrow=nrow(a), ncol=ncol(a), byrow=TRUE)
c <- matrix(data=rep(rowMeans(a), ncol(a)), nrow=nrow(a), ncol=ncol(a), byrow=FALSE)
d <- matrix(data=rep(mean(a), nrow(a)*ncol(a)), nrow=nrow(a), ncol=ncol(a), byrow=FALSE)
e <- a-b-c-d
```

colMeans can be sweep out by using this command

```
a1 <- sweep(a, 2, colMeans(a), "-")
```

Is there any single command to sweep out colMeans, rowMeans and mean? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think `e`should look like in this example? Perhaps your line should be `e <- a-b-c+d` so that `e` has zero mean.

The following code produces the same result as your calculation using `b`, `c`, and `d` (with your arithmetic progression example, a matrix of 0s).  Change `+`to `-` if you insist.

```
 e <- t(t(a) - colMeans(a)) - rowMeans(a) + mean(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, but why not just write your own? It's only four lines:

```
meanSweep <- function(x){
    tmp <- sweep(x,2,colMeans(x),"-")
    tmp <- sweep(tmp,1,rowMeans(x),"-")
    tmp <- tmp - mean(x)
    tmp
}

all.equal(e,meanSweep(a))
[1] TRUE
```